# Copyright if I continue someone else's work

Tags: novel, publishing, copyright, quotes, manuscripts

I am writing a book - continuing someone's book series. They were finished but I'd really like to see the other characters' lives. I need to quote (I wouldn't say really quote but let's call that quoting) or rather explain the other author's book in a chapter so my readers understand what I'm writing about. Can that part get copyrighted and my work put in the trash? I'd quite literally describe everything that happened there in a chapter. The words I used are pretty much the same although I did not copy the text from the original book, only explained what happened there.
Can someone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> I am writing a book - continuing someone's book series.

I'm sorry to say that you're *already* infringing copyright. **You cannot publish books about other people's characters without their permission.**

If you're just writing a fanfic that you intend to publish online for free, that's fine. As long as you're not profiting from it, and the original author hasn't forbidden fanfics of their work (Anne McCaffrey being an example of a writer who has done that), then you shouldn't run into any legal issues.

It sounds like you intend to publish this as a physical book, however, in which case, I strongly recommend that you **don't do that**, and just publish your story somewhere like FanFiction.net instead. If you try and get this sold in bookstores, you are going to get sued the second the copyright holder finds out about it.

Comment: She can get into trouble for publishing fan fiction.  Anne McCaffrey had to ask the fanfic community to stop publishing works set in Pern to protect her rights.

Comment: @EDL That's a good point, I should have clarified that to start with. I've now done so.

Comment: And if I'd contact the author and ask for premission?

Comment: It's worth a try, but you'll have to be prepared for the possibility that they'll say no.

Comment: Would it be smarter to finish the first book (out of six) and then ask or start out with asking?

Comment: I think it would be smarter to ask for permission as soon as possible, so you know ahead of time what you can and can't do with the book once it's complete.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll definitely take everything in count! :)

Comment: In theory, publishing it online can get you in trouble, it's just that it's not worth the bother to most writers.

Comment: @EmmaEdwards Fan fiction is a huge legal grey area. Most IP owners *tolerate* fan fiction as long as it's non-commercial because fighting it is usually more trouble than it's worth (both legally and PR-wise). But they don't *have* to tolerate it and some don't. It's always a good idea to confirm what stance the IP owner (who might or might not be the author) has on fan fiction before starting to write. See [the wikipedia article on the legality of fan fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_with_fan_fiction) for more information.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of fan-fiction so I'll try to contact the author (I have found some contact information) and see how it goes :)